# Out of order dictionary keys after merging in Python

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, dictionary, merge, key

After merging two dictionaries, the subkeys form the resulted dictionary are disorderly. Subkeys are months ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', ... , 'dec']. In some cases, an original dictionary might not contain a subkey (month) so the output gets disoredered with the merge.

So I have two dictionaries both with the next structure 
    `{Model:{'Jan':[1], 'Feb':[2], Jun: [5], ...}`

As you can see in this example, some subkeys (months) are not represented, so they can't be found it the original dicts. But, what I need is the merged dict to keep the monthly order, doesn't matter how original dicts were looking like.

The merging function:

```py
def merge_dicts(dict1, dict2):
    '''Marge two dicts by adding up (accumulating) values in each key.

    Returns: A merge (addition) of two dictionaries by adding values of same keys
    '''
   # Merge dictionaries and add values of same keys
    out = {**dict1, **dict2}
    for key, value in out.items():
        if key in dict1 and key in dict2:
            out[key] = [value, dict1[key]]
            #Things got harder, out[key] appends in list of list of list... no itertools can help here.
            lst = [] #the one dimensional list to fix the problem of list of list with out[key]
            for el in out[key]:
                try:
                #if inside out[key] there is a list of list we split it
                    for sub_el in el:
                        lst.append(sub_el)
                except:
                #if inside out[key] there is only a single float
                    lst.append(el)
            #Replace the old key with the one dimensional list
            out[key] = lst
    return out
```

How I merge it:

```py
for c in range(len([*CMs_selection.keys()])):
    if c == 0:
        #First merge, with dict0 & dict1
        merged_dict = {cm:merge_dicts(CMs_selection[[*CMs_selection.keys()][c]][cm], CMs_selection[[*CMs_selection.keys()][c + 1]][cm]) 
                       for cm in CMs_selection[[*CMs_selection.keys()][0]]}

    elif c > 0 and c < (len(years) - 1):
        #Second merge to n merge, starting with dict_merged and dict 2
        merged_dict = {cm:merge_dicts(merged_dict[cm], CMs_selection[[*CMs_selection.keys()][c + 1]][cm]) 
                       for cm in CMs_selection[[*CMs_selection.keys()][0]]}
```

Right now, after trying all the merging possible I am getting this results always.

```
{'Model1': {'Jan': [-0.0952586755156517,
   0.1015196293592453,
   -0.10572463274002075],
  'Oct': [-0.02473766915500164,
   0.0678798109292984,
   0.08870666474103928,
   -0.06378963589668274],
  'Nov': [-0.08730728179216385,
   0.013518977910280228,
   0.023245899006724358,
   -0.03917887806892395],
  'Jul': [-0.07940272241830826, -0.04912888631224632, -0.07454635202884674],
  'Dec': [-0.061335086822509766, -0.0033914903178811073, 0.09630533307790756],
  'Mar': [0.029064208269119263, 0.11327305436134338, 0.009556809440255165],
  'Apr': [-0.04433680325746536, -0.08620205521583557],
  'Jun': [-0.036688946187496185, 0.05543896555900574, -0.07162825018167496],
  'Aug': -0.03712410107254982,
  'Sep': [0.007421047426760197, 0.008665643632411957],
  'Feb': [-0.02879650704562664, 0.013025006279349327]},
 'Model2': {'Feb': -0.05173473060131073,
  'Jun': [-0.09126871824264526,
   -0.09009774029254913,
   0.10458160936832428,
   -0.09445420652627945,
   -0.04294373467564583],
  'Aug': [-0.07917020469903946, 0.011026041582226753],
  'Oct': [-0.10164830088615417, ....
```

....

With disorderly months. Please help me!

Comment: Could you just share a complete example about what you want exactly?

Comment: @Alperen sure! Thanks for your interest!
So what is want is that the merged dictionary (output) keeps the months (subkeys) ordered. Like
{'Model1': {'Jan': [-0.09, 0.1   -0.8],
  'Feb': [ ],
  'Mar': [-0.23, 5],
  'Apr' : [ ],
  'May': [0.3, 1],
...
   'Dec': [ ... ]},
'Model2': {'Jan': [whatever values..],
  'Feb': [ ....]
so just keep the months ordered.
If you have any question just let me now!!

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand especially the edge cases. Correct me if I'm wrong. As far as I understand, you are somehow sending `Model1` and `Model2` to the `merge_dicts` function. Then, lets talk about just `merge_dicts` function. For example, if we have `dict1 = {"Jan":[0], "Feb":[0]}` and `dict2 = {"Feb":[1], "Mar":[1]}`, we should return `{'Jan': [0], 'Feb': [0, 1], 'Mar': [1]}`. Right?

Comment: RIght! When I merge, _dict1_ &_dict2_ come from the same dict: **CMs_selection**, separated by years. I just merge all the years in one single dict **merged_dict**. The input **CMs_selection** looks like:
`{2006: {'Model1': {'Jan': -0.1,
   'Oct': -0.063},
  'Model2': {'Feb': -0.051,
   'Jun': -0.04,
   'Oct': 0.07},
  'Model3': {'Mar': -0.030,
   'Jun': 0.02,
   'Aug': 0.0561,},
  'Model4': {'Feb': -0.026,
...
   'Dec': -0.06}},
 2007: {'Model1': {'Jul': -0.07,
   'Oct': 0.8,
   'Nov': 0.38,
   'Dec': 0.1},
  'Model2': {'Jun': -0.09,
   'Aug': -0.079,
   'Sep': -0.7,
...`

Comment: Try my updated answer. Changed it for your last example `CMs_selection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we just focus on merging dictionaries, first, we need to define the normal order of months, then make the merging in that order because Python doesn't know this order. It cannot add "Mar" between "Feb" and "Apr" if it doesn't exist at the first dictionary. So, we need to define the order ourself.

Also, you need two different solution for merging float values and merging lists. I added `mode` parameter to my solution.

```
def merge_dicts(list_of_dicts, mode):
    keys = set(key for d in list_of_dicts for key in d.keys())
    months = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]
    ordered_keys = [month for month in months if month in keys]

    out = {}
    for key in ordered_keys:
        out[key] = []
        for d in list_of_dicts:
            if key in d:
                if mode == "append":
                    out[key].append(d[key]) 
                elif mode == "extend":
                    out[key].extend(d[key])

    return out


CMs_selection = {2006: {'Model1': {'Jan': -0.1, 'Oct': -0.063}, 'Model2': {'Feb': -0.051, 'Jun': -0.04, 'Oct': 0.07}, 'Model3': {'Mar': -0.030, 'Jun': 0.02, 'Aug': 0.0561,}, 'Model4': {'Feb': -0.026, 'Dec': -0.06}}, 2007: {'Model1': {'Jul': -0.07, 'Oct': 0.8, 'Nov': 0.38, 'Dec': 0.1}, 'Model2': {'Jun': -0.09, 'Aug': -0.079, 'Sep': -0.7}}}

for key in CMs_selection:
    CMs_selection[key] = merge_dicts(CMs_selection[key].values(), "append")

print(CMs_selection)

result = merge_dicts(CMs_selection.values(), "extend")
print(result)
```

Output:

```
{2006: {'Jan': [-0.1], 'Feb': [-0.051, -0.026], 'Mar': [-0.03], 'Jun': [-0.04, 0.02], 'Aug': [0.0561], 'Oct': [-0.063, 0.07], 'Dec': [-0.06]}, 2007: {'Jun': [-0.09], 'Jul': [-0.07], 'Aug': [-0.079], 'Sep': [-0.7], 'Oct': [0.8], 'Nov': [0.38], 'Dec': [0.1]}}
{'Jan': [-0.1], 'Feb': [-0.051, -0.026], 'Mar': [-0.03], 'Jun': [-0.04, 0.02, -0.09], 'Jul': [-0.07], 'Aug': [0.0561, -0.079], 'Sep': [-0.7], 'Oct': [-0.063, 0.07, 0.8], 'Nov': [0.38], 'Dec': [-0.06, 0.1]}
```

Comment: I have have solved it! Thanks a lot, in the end I keep the structure but from the very begining I defined a merge_dict that contanied monthly subkeys. Afterwards I have iterated for each model.

Thanks a lot for your feedback because I know that this was quite a hard question (and bad explained from my side).
Best!!

Comment: Glad to hear that.